# Run automatically sh script on wsl2 startup

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I need to run the script every time I start the wsl machine. It's very annoying to keep typing `sh /root/webstart.sh` when I turn on wsl.

Does anyone have a similar experience with this?

How can i achieve this result please?

Answer (score 0):

So i already find out, that if I add in /etc/bash.bashrc my code, it will automatically start after I run wsl.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/bashrc-file-in-linux